# Keep getting a 502 error on nodejs server

Tags: node.js

I keep getting 502 to all my style sheets and pictures on a webserver on webfaction and local webserver. I am not sure what i am doing wrong?? I have to hit 3 times on the production webserver for all the resources to properly load. Any help? I do have big pictures on my page but i don't think they are causing the issue.

these are my response headers on production server

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 08 Dec 2013 07:47:55 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Express
```

This is my app.js on node.

```
var pagejs= '../routes';
var express = require('express')
  , home = require(pagejs)
  , user = require(pagejs+'/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , events = require(pagejs+'/events')
  , contact= require(pagejs+'/contact')
  , abouttedx = require(pagejs+'/about')
  , sponsor = require(pagejs+'/sponsors')
  , gzippo = require('gzippo');

var app = express();

function viewConfig(app){
  app.set('views', __dirname + './../views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  //app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname + './../public/images/favicon.ico')));
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
//app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  //app.set('view options', {layout: false });
  //app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './../public')));
  app.use(gzippo.staticGzip(path.join(__dirname, './../public')));
  app.use(gzippo.compress());
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 9000);
}

app.configure('production', function(){
    viewConfig(app); 
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
  viewConfig(app);
});

app.get('/', home.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/events', events.eventspage);
app.get('/about', abouttedx.aboutpage);
app.get('/sponsor', sponsor.sponsorpage);
app.get('/contact', contact.contactuspage);


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your nginx configuration. Can you share how you have configured nginx to talk to node server?

Comment: I haven't configured anything on nginx server.

Comment: The headers included in your post indicate that your node server is proxied behind nginx. Looks like someone else manages the production setup, do read about nginx + node setup, google is your best friend! I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out on your own, let us know if you face any issue.

Comment: @vmx, seems like the nginx server is already installed on my webserver

Comment: That is obvious from first look at your question. Nginx + Node is a common setup used by many, myself included. Now you'll have to configure nginx to talk to your node server. I will illustration this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed `myapp.com` to be the web application we are trying to set up.

Check your server configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.com`. Adapt it similar to this;

```
server {
  server_name myapp.com;

  # set nginx root to public dir of your express server
  root /var/www/myapp/releases/current/public/;

  index index.html index.htm;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp.error.log;

  location ~ ^/(js|css|images|media|system)/ {
    autoindex off;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    expires 4w;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @proxy;
  }

  location @proxy {
    # set proxy pass to your node server
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

Test nginx config and reload;

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Now nginx receives your request and proxies it to your node server. Let me know if this works for you. You can share your nginx configuration if it still doesn't work.

Comment: In my production server it won't give me access to change the file or add a file. Is there a way you can include like the file .htaccess in my public folder in nginx to configure?

Comment: unless you have access to change nginx configuration, this will be difficult to resolve. I don't know how to help you out here.